# Who is the main character of Fairy Tail?

Tags: fairy-tail

Who is the main character of Fairy Tail? Would it be Natsu or Lucy? Natsu is like the hero of the whole anime, but I think the main story revolves around Lucy, how she met Natsu and how she joined Fairy Tail etc. I read the description of Fairy Tail and it says:

> Lucy is a 16-year-old girl, who wants to be a full-fledged mage. One day when visiting Harujion Town, she meets Natsu, a young man who gets sick easily by any type of transportation. But Natsu isn't just any ordinary kid, he's a member of one of the world's most infamous mage guilds: Fairy Tail.

Preferably if we could draw an in a canon answer (e.g. interviews with the authors etc.), who would be the main character of Fairy Tail? Natsu or Lucy?

Comment: Surely every person will have a different **opinion** depending on what character they most like.

Comment: Neither. Main character is Happy.

Comment: @Oded Sorry, but I don't agree with your comment. In naruto, naruto is the main character. In bleach, its Ichigo. And in One Piece, its Luffy. So, even people have different favourite characters, there is always only one main character.

Comment: @ton.yeung Aye sir XD

Comment: In the three series you commented about, it is rather clear cut. With Fairy Tail, not so much (you are asking for opinions of people here, after all).

Comment: @Oded But its a valid question i guess. There must be one main character.

Comment: @Oded Not true, there can be several protagonists/main characters in a series. It is not specifically bound to 1 character. It depends on their importance in the serie. As a side node, in for example Naruto it is stated that Naruto, Kakashi, Sakura and Sasuke are considerd Main Characters. Although it might feel as if Naruto is more important over all

Comment: I'd like to echo Dimitrimx. Take gundam age for example, the main character torch gets passed on through the generations. Granted, there is one main character at a time. However, the point is that the series has *more than one main character*. @berserk, if you insist that there must be one main character, please site the "rule" that *there must only be one*. (insert dramatic tone in here, anyone catch the plug? :D )

Comment: Yeah, Fairy Tail definitely has more of group of main characters than the others. In One Piece for example, although all the Straw Hats are main characters, Luffy is obviously the single main character. In Fairy Tail Natsu and Lucy are the main characters, and it's not obvious who takes precedence. Natsu is the hero of the story, but Lucy is for the most part the character whose point of view we see the story from.

Comment: Lucy at more than one occasions plays the part of a narrator whereas natsu mostly acts as the protagonist.

Comment: @ton.yeung Understood :D

Comment: I nominated question for reopening. I think I have narrowed the question a bit more and I think, given the chance, it can be answered properly.

Comment: @berserk- Hey, and I know you haven't been asking a lot of questions, but don't forget you can always chat with us in the chat room. I kind of created a chat room and wouldn't mind you joining really. But this question really, I think could be answered reasonably.

Comment: I think its lucy because she is always being the hostage and being saved by natsu and the others.I can say because many episodes that she is always in danger but save at the last part.And also most stories are about her

Comment: @Izumi-reiLuLu Sorry for late reply. What is the name of the room?

Comment: There were times it seemed where the main protagonist would switch between Lucy and Natsu. (I only watched the anime and this seemed like it to me)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Introduction in first chapter

Usually the main purpose of a manga is explained in the first chapter, being the introduction to the complete story. In that sense both Natsu and Lucy would be the main protagonists. Both Natsu, Lucy (and Happy) are introduced in the first chapter. Natsu, who is searching for Igneel, while Lucy wants to join Fairytail and become a great Celestial mage.

### Introduction of Natsu (and Happy)

[image: enter image description here!]

### Introduction of Lucy

[image: enter image description here!]

### Both Natsu and Lucy mention their goal in the story

[image: enter image description here!]

### Title

On the other hand, the title usually points towards the main story too, like with *One Piece*, where Luffy is searching for the One Piece. In that sense Lucy should be more considered as being the main character as her story actually revolves around Fairytail, since she doesn't just want to be just any mage, she wants to be a `FairyTail` mage. Natsu just happens to be in Fairytail, but his story doesn't really revolve around his guild. He just wants to find his father.

### Wikipedia

The Wikipedia page on Fairy Tail agrees on this, saying:

> Fairy Tail follows the adventures of Lucy Heartfilia, a teenage wizard (魔導士 madōshi?),[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMUdCm.png) who joins the titular wizards' guild and teams up with fellow guild member Natsu Dragneel as he searches for the dragon Igneel.

Natsu is an important person to the story, and he is also introduced first of all, even before Lucy, but going by this Wikipedia quote I would say Lucy would be the main (and only?) protagonist.

Comment: Very nice answer :)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion Natsu is the main character, because at the root he is the one that everyone in fairy tail relies on. It can be clearly seen that all important fights include Natsu at the core. Even though Erza, Laxus and Gray and all others are powerful, still Natsu is the one that always fights hardest and finishes the battle.

In the episode where everyone is on Tenrou island, Zeref's magic was unable to kill Natsu because of his scarf. Also Zeref said that Natsu was still not ready to kill him and Zeref and demons from his book are the evil mages.

So IMHO Natsu is the Protagonist

Comment: No problem and welcome to the Manga & Anime SE. Hope you enjoy it here. If you have any questions feel free to ask, there are lots of nice people out here willing to help :)

Comment: I am looking forward to it.

Answer (score 2):

There are 5 main protagonists: ***Natsu, Happy, Gray, Erza and Lucy.***

I feel the story revolves around them more than just one of them.
They are all important to the plot of Fairy Tail, as if one were removed, the story probably wouldn't be as intriguing as it is now.
So I say that there is no main character, but a bunch of main characters altogether.

Answer (score 2):

It would seem Lucy is the main character, as [Peter Raeves said](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/who-is-the-main-character-of-fairy-tail/11177#11177), both Natsu and Lucy are mentioned in the first chapter (and episode).

In the more recent chapters

> when Fairy Tail split up, the story came back to focus on Lucy and on what she was doing, then slowly adding Natsu, then Juvia and then Gray.

Comment: For help with formatting and editing, you should try this https://anime.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Lucy would be the main protagonist, seeing as the story is mainly revolves around her. Though Natsu is the main male protagonist and Lucy the main female protagonist - sorta like *Rave Master* (or simply *Rave*), another work by Hiro Mashima, with Haru as the main protagonist/main male protagonist and Elie as the main female protagonist.